# Laravel 5 eager loading user relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eager-loading

I have a `User` model, the `User` has a n-n relationship with `Widget`. The pivot table in this case is called `dashboards`. The `dashboard` table has the following columns:

`x`, `y`, `widget_id` and `user_id`.

I am trying to Eager Load the Dashboard table so that the Front-end can retrieve it while retrieving a `User`.

My `User` model essentially looks like this (other relationships excluded):

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements AuthenticatableUserContract {
use Notifiable, Loggable, SoftDeletes, HasPolicy;


protected $fillable = [
    'email',
    'role_id',
    'permissions',
    'disallowed',
];

protected $hidden = [
    'google_token',
];

protected $with = [
    'widgets', //breaks code
];  

public function widgets() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Widget::class, 'dashboards')->withPivot(['x', 'y']);
}
```

Somehow the `protected $with` bit breaks the application, preventing the `User` to be authenticated. It somehow corrupts the `User` but I have no idea why. I have used `protected $with` perfectly fine the same way in some other models so I don't think I'm using it wrong.

The error it throws is `Call to a member function cannot() on null`
Which would refer to this line of code `if( Auth::user()->cannot('read', $policyClass )`. If I don't put `$with` in it passes through fine..

HasPolicy.php:

```
namespace App\Traits;

use Auth;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Gate;

trait HasPolicy {

protected static function bootHasPolicy() {
    static::loaded( function ($model) {
        foreach ($model->with as $relation) {
            $policyClass = get_class($model->$relation()->getRelated());
            if( Auth::user()->cannot('read', $policyClass ) && app(Gate::class)->getPolicyFor($policyClass) ) {
                unset($model->with[array_search($relation, $model->with)]);
            }
        }
    });
}

public function newFromBuilder($attributes = [], $connection = null) {
    $instance = parent::newFromBuilder($attributes, $connection);

    $instance->fireModelEvent('loaded');

    return $instance;
}

/**
 * Register a loaded model event with the dispatcher.
 *
 * @param  \Closure|string  $callback
 * @param  int  $priority
 * @return void
 */
public static function loaded($callback) {
    static::registerModelEvent('loaded', $callback);
}
}
```

Why does the `$with` prevent the `User` from being Authenticated? What should I be looking at?

Stacktrace:
https://pastebin.com/16J3cptM

Comment: I tried to reproduce it on a clean laravel 5.4 instance and it doesn't happen. To be clear I: created `User` and `Widget` models. Created `users`, `widgets`, `dashboards` tables as you specified and filled with some data. Ddded `$with` property and `widgets()` method on `User`. Verified that eager loading was working (inspecting MySQL queries). Then, tried an `Auth::attempt()` with some users (tried both with users with a relationship and user without). The login works. I don't find the `if( Auth::user()->cannot('read', $policyClass )` in Laravel codebase, where is it?

Comment: @LombaX It's in our custom Trait called `HasPolicy`, updated the question with the full code

Comment: It's not so easy to understand where the problem is without analyzing the context around the code you posted. In some way, it seems that the `Auth::user()` starts to returning null instead of the current user when you add the `$with` relationship. Since I tried in a clean Laravel I don't think that the problem is related to the framework but somehow to the context around the code you posted. Try to post the backtrace of the error (if you enable debug Laravel will give it automatically in the error page), it could help

Comment: @LombaX I have updated the question with a link to a pastebin with the stacktrace, thanks so far

Comment: I see, unfortunately it seems more complex that I thought and it's difficult to understand without a debugger. I suspect the something happens in `HasPivotEvents.php` but I think that the best thing you can do is to use XDebug, then inspect all the call stack (focusing mainly on the custom sources) and understand why without `$with` the Auth::user() returns the user correctly and with `$with` no. If your sources can be published with all the needed data to reproduce the problem, I can have a look with xdebug